# Scores in a file to dictionary in python?

Tags: python, dictionary

I want to make a dictionary entry from a file that has several lines: if the line is only numeric, it will be a value, but if it is not (i.e. mostly alpha), it will be the key for the following numbers, until another name comes up in the file. I haven't been able to figure out how to get the code to "start over"/continue by making a new key when it reaches the next name.

The file looks something like this:

```
Gigi:
0
2
3
2
Bella:
1
6
2
9
```

And I would like to have a dictionary that looks like this:

```
{Gigi: [0,2,3,2], Bella: [1,6,2,9]}
```

Comment: Have you written anything to attempt this?

Comment: Could you show us what you have so far? StackOverflow isn't really something for people to write you a program, it's more of helping you with problems inside your program.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my_dict = {}
current_key = None
for line in open('/path/to/file', 'r'):
    if not line.strip().isdigit():
        current_key = line.strip()
        my_dict[current_key] = []
    else:
        my_dict[current_key].append(int(line.strip()))
```

First set an empty dictionary to add the keys and values to it, then a variable to keep track of the current key until a next non-digit replaces it, finally iterate over the lines in the file, if it is not a digit it is set as the current key and added to the dictionary as an empty list, and if it is a digit it is converted to integer and appended to the dictionary entry of the current key.

Edit:
This expects the first line to be a key, if digits appear first, there will be no corresponding key in the dictionary to append the values.